# arclength parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry

Find the arclength parametrization of the curve

$$r(t) = (t, \frac{1}{2}t^2 ), t>=0$$
I find that |r'(t)| = $\sqrt{1+t^2}$

I try to integrate it but it looks horrible and I don't know what to do next. Can anyone help me?

Comment: put $t=sinh(u)$ and use $1+sinh^2=cosh^2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$r(t)=\int \sqrt{1+t^2}dt=
\int ch^2(u)du$  using $t=sh(u)$.

but $ch^2(u)=\frac{1+ch(2u)}{2}$

thus

$r(t)=\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{1}{4}sh(2u)$

$=\frac{1}{2}argsh(t)+\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{1+t^2}$.