# arclength parametrization of t

Tags: differential-geometry

Find the arclength parametrization of the curve

$$r(t) = (t, \frac{1}{2}at^2 ), t>=0$$
let $\alpha(s)$ be the arc length parametrization such that $\alpha(0)=(0,0)$

question: Find $T(s)$ and $N(s)$ at $s=0$.

I find that |r'(t)| = $\sqrt{1+a^2t^2}$

I try to integrate it and find $s(t)=\frac{1}{2a}argsh(at)+\frac{1}{2a}at\sqrt{1+a^2t^2}$. But it looks horrible and I don't know what to find $t(s)$ . Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that $T(0)$ is the normalised velocity vector, so this is easy to compute. You know that $N(0)$ is orthogonal to this, so there are only two choices, and you can guess the answer. Also, the question as stated does not require that you compute $\alpha(s)$.

Comment: Is [arclength parametrization](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955542) you, a classmate with freakishly similar typographical habits, or an astronomical coincidence...? (If the first, please don't re-ask the same question. Thank you.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: This question is different, it asks for the tangent and normal vectors (which are independent of the parameterisation, so the OP is doing more work than necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma(t) =\int_0^t \|r'(x)\| dx$ from which we have $\sigma'(t) = \|r'(t)\|$, and $\sigma(0) = 0$.

Since $r$ is regular we see that $\sigma$
is strictly increasing and hence invertible on the range, hence there is some
$\tau$ such that $\tau(\sigma(t)) = t$. We see that
$\tau'(\sigma(t)) = {1 \over \sigma'(t)} = { 1\over \|r'(\sigma(t))\|}$, or
$\tau'(x) = { 1\over \|r'(x)\|}$.

Then $\alpha(s) = r(\tau(s))$, and so $T(s) = \alpha'(s) = r'(\tau(s)) \tau'(s) = { r'(\tau(s)) \over \|r'(\tau(s)\| }$, and
hence $T(0) = { r'(0) \over \|r'(0 \| } = (1,0)$.

We have $N(s) = {T'(s) \over \|T'(s)\|}$. Cranking through the composition
and quotient rules, we obtain
$T'(s) = (I-{ r'(\tau(s)) r'(\tau(s))^T\over \|r'(\tau(s))\|^2 }) {r''(\tau(s)) \over \|r'(\tau(s))\| }  $,
and so
$T'(0) = (I-{ r'(0) r'(0)^T\over \|r'(0)\|^2 }) {r''(0) \over \|r'(0)\| }$, from which you
can calculate $N(0) = (0, \operatorname{sgn} a)$.

Note that there was no need to explicitly compute $s$.